# Добавление заказа в Базу данных, и проверка на доступность

Tags: mysql, java-ee, servlet

Направьте на путь истинный. Есть интернет-магазин. Есть корзина товаров (данные о корзине хранятся в сессии). 
Используется: Java, servlet, js, Mysql

Клиент набивает корзину и собирается оформить заказ. 
1) Нужно узнать, возможно ли сформировать такой заказ, т.е выясняем хватит товаров на складе или нет (в БД существует таблица с товарами и полем "количество").
2) Если товаров хватает то добавить заказ в БД (существует 2 связанные таблицы: заказ и состав заказа).
3) Как правильно добавить запись в таблицу "Order" и "OrderList". 
 В первой поля: id, user_id, status, date
 Во второй: order_id, product_id, price (тут может быть несколько записей для одного заказа).

**Как правильно и красиво проверить возможность сформировать заказ?**

**Мои мысли:** сделать запрос `select * from product`. Ответ запихнуть в `List<Product> products`. И далее через цикл ищем, если товаров хватает, то делаем следующий запрос, если нет, то возвращаем ответ о нехватке товаров на складе.
По второму вопросу: Я думал делать запросы в цикле. Или можно как-то сделать через хранимые процедуры?

```
for (OrderList pr : orderlist){
 statement2.setInt(1, pr.getProduct_id());
 statement2.setInt(2, pr.getAmount());
 statement2.setInt(3, pr.getPrice());
 statement2.executeUpdate();
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Запрос на добавление заказа:

```
INSERT INTO `orders` (`users_ID`, `status`, `date`) VALUES ('2', 'PROCESSED', '2018-09-04 04:36:00');
```

Далее идут запросы:

```js
INSERT INTO `orders_list` (`orders_ID`, `products_ID`, `amount`, `price`) VALUES ('42', '2', '13', '1500');
INSERT INTO `orders_list` (`orders_ID`, `products_ID`, `amount`, `price`) VALUES ('42', '5', '8', '2500');
INSERT INTO `orders_list` (`orders_ID`, `products_ID`, `amount`, `price`) VALUES ('42', '7', '2', '1000');
INSERT INTO `orders_list` (`orders_ID`, `products_ID`, `amount`, `price`) VALUES ('42', '21', '1', '5000');
```

Где orders_ID, это автоинкрементный ID главной таблицы

Comment: Не проще ли взять из сессии id-шники товаров которые пользователь хочет купить и з БД вытянуть данные только по этим товарам? `select * from products where id in (....)

Comment: Так все равно мне нужно будет изменить количество товаров на складе, как это сделать одним запросом если товаров несколько?

Comment: Используйте транзакции. В одной транзакции добавляем заказ и уменьшаем кол-во товара на складе

Comment: А как добавить заказ если он состоит из двух таблиц со связью one-to-many. В главной таблице храню ID, ID_user, date. Во второй order_id, product_id, count_ price.

Comment: обновил вопрос в поле UPDATE, если можете посмотрите

Comment: Зачем price в OrderList? У вас для разных заказов разные цены на один и тот же товар? А вот поле количество здесь бы не помешало.

Comment: Тоже над этим думал, сделал новую цену на случай если цена в прайсе измениться, а человек сделал оформляет заказ, чтобы цена первоначальная не изменилось. Хотя его убрать не проблема, основной вопрос как правильно организовать добавление заказа. С точки зрения связных таблиц, и с учетом того что во вторую таблицу может упасть несколько записей.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
1. START TRANSACTION
2. итератором бежим по продуктам в корзине: 
2.1. обновляем записи в БД: 
update product set amount = amount - 1 where id=? and amount > 0
(здесь если результат executeUpdate()==0 то делаем break и ROLLBACK TRANSACTION)
2.2 добавляем записи в orders и orders_list
3. COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Comment: 2.1 и 2.2 делаем в цикле? for (Order ol : orderlist) {
  // тут собственно сами запросы
 statement.setInt(1, ol.getPrice());
        statement.executeUpdate();
}  И как сделать несколько запросов в java, несколько statement создавать надо?

Comment: Да 2.1, 2.2 делаем в цикле. Перед циклом получаешь инстанс коннекта и далее в цикле меняем sql запрос и после statement2 = connection.prepareStatement(sql)